# Pyspark to filter date in format yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: python, string, datetime, pyspark, timestamp

I want to filter my data for Datetime column in the format yyy-mm-dd. However, its string value and there is a timestamp associated with the date. I don't want this timestamp in my column. I am using Pyspark for it.

Format of date- 2021/09/23 09:00:00+00,

Format to be done- 2021-09-23

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date
df = df_pyspark.withColumn("date_only",to_date(col("DateTime"))) #col name in data is DateTime
```

The `date_only` is showing null values. How should I approach here?

Comment: A date column does not have a format. It is stored internally as a timestamp (an int). Only when the data are shown, it is converted to a human readeable format, generally `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.s`

Comment: Here in this case, date is a string, how do i remove the timestamp from it?

Comment: you want a string with the timestamp part removed ? a string with a different date format (`-` dashes instead of `/` slashes) ? or a simple date column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the fonction [`to_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date), you need to pass a format string. The format string can be created using the official documentation for [simpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) - avaialble from the spark documentation directly.
In your case, the format is `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ssX` :

```py
df.withColumn("t", F.to_date("datetime", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ssX")).show(truncate=False)                                                                                              
+----------------------+----------+
|DateTime              |t         |
+----------------------+----------+
|2021/09/23 09:00:00+00|2021-09-23|
+----------------------+----------+
```

---

you can then filter on the date :

```py
df.where(F.to_date("datetime", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ssX") == "2021-09-23").show()                                                                                                       
+--------------------+                                                          
|            DateTime|
+--------------------+
|2021/09/23 09:00:...|
+--------------------+
```